# Unity Load text from resources

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm able to change the text of a `UILabel` (named about) with the following:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class about : MonoBehaviour
{
   void Start ()
   {
      UILabel lbl = GetComponent<UILabel>();
      lbl.text = "Hello World!";
   }
}
```

However things go awry when I want to load the label text from a text file in resources (`Assets/Resources/about.txt`)

```
lbl.text = Resources.Load(Application.dataPath + "/Resources/about") as String
```

So I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, and yes I have looked [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html).

Comment: Wait, when you say you are changing a "UILabel", do you mean an actual UILabel in Xcode, like an iOS API UILabel?  Or are you just using the term "UILabel" to refer to a Label in Unity?  I just ask because UILabel is the API name for labels in iOS, and if you were accessing the iOS API from Unity code that would be a pretty impressive feat....

Answer (score 18):

Simply use this:

```
TextAsset mytxtData=(TextAsset)Resources.Load("MyText");
string txt=mytxtData.text;
```

and you can use the `txt` string to fulfill your requirement, just make sure that `MyText.txt` is in `Assets > Resources`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks, fellas.

Comment: In case anyone was commiting the same mistake as I: the string with the file name should not include the extension. So for `file.txt`, one should use `Resources.Load("file")`.

Comment: Thanks for this! My problem was that my Unity project didn't have a Resources folder. If it's going to be so vital that you need to put certain files into it to make them programmatically accessible, you'd think it would be created automatically for you!

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried one of these:

```
TextAsset mydata = Resources.Load("MyTexts/text", typeof(TextAsset));
TextAsset mydata = Resources.Load("MyTexts/text") as TextAsset;
```

Here, `"MyTexts/text"` is the asset name, which will actual refere the file `text.txt`.

The asset should be placed inside the Assets folder this way:

```
Assets/MyTexts/text
```

On the filesystem you will have:

```
.../Assets/MyTexts/text.txt
```

Don't use `Application.dataPath` or anything like that, you're loading a statically linked asset from the binary asset file.

The loaded `mydata` is binary. Use `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(mydata.bytes)` to get an actual string out of it.

Comment: That just gets me the errors CS0119: Expression denotes a `type', where a `variable', `value' or `method group' was expected &  error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Resources.Load(string, System.Type)' has some invalid arguments & error CS1503: Argument `#2' cannot convert `object' expression to type `System.Type'

Comment: Ough... yess! Sorry, that was an oversight. I've corrected it and added another way to write it. Now it should work :)

Comment: TextAsset mytext = Resources.Load("text") as TextAsset; loads the file (I've checked it with Debug.Log. The problem remaining is to get `lbl.text = mytext` to work. I get the error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.TextAsset' to `string'

Comment: Added last line for string conversion and corrected a last typo.

Comment: Additionally, you may use `string[] txtLines = myData.text.Split('\n');` if you're loading a file that you need to store line by line.

Answer (score 3):

I searched for alot of methods online and implemented them, but none of them worked. So I went to Unity docs. Here is a link hope it helps.
[Unity Read Resource](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) 
 **Read it carefully.**

Edit:
here is a simple implementation:

- Create Resources folder in Assets.
- Place your text file in that folder(Resources).

code:

```
var textFile = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("file name only not path and no file extension(.txt)");

//store it in any List line by line(optional)
List<String> words = new List<string>(textFile.text.Split('\n'));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var loaded_text_file = Resources.Load("mytexts/myfiletextname") as TextAsset;

string txt = loaded_text_file.text;
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having a hard time loading 'TextAsset' files, until I discovered that only certain file extensions can be used.  In my case I was trying to use '.yml', but unity will only read '.yaml'.

Full details here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextAsset.html