# Android/data/com.project.xx/files directory missing Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to use Application.persistentDataPath to save to device.  What I'm seeing though is that its coming back null.  I looked on device and am not seeing a files folder on my device, which makes me think that's why I'm getting back null.  So I'm wondering how I can make sure a files directory is made when built to device using Unity.

Comment: You are not new to SO, so you should know by now to include code in your question.

Comment: What code is there to show? im using Application.persistentDataPath and it was coming back null???

Comment: I apologize for asking for your save code that uses `Application.persistentDataPath`. Please **don't** post your code when having problems. By not posting your code, anyone willing to help will be able to find out the problems you are having. Happy Coding!

Comment: I have no problem showing my code when its relevant you want code:     `   destPath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/Video.mp4";
        Debug.Log("FILE PATH: " + destPath);`

Answer (score 0):

To work with Mobile devices, you should try saving and loading files from Resources folder. All the files in Resources will be copied to your devices.

[Unity Load text from resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583104/unity-load-text-from-resources)

Comment: Im trying to save to device for downloaded content, which isn't going to be stored on the device when built.