# Cannot access JSON file from Streaming Assets in android build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm relatively new to Unity. I ran into the following problem when I built it for android. The JSON file doesn't load on build. However, it loads in editor.

I've tried multiple techniques, like Streaming Assets folder, Resources, persistentDataPath. None of them seems to be working for builds.

```
public class setting_data
{
    private Eng_WB_Question[] gamedata; 
    private string filename = "words.json";
    public Eng_WB_Controller controller;
    string json_data;
    private void Start()
    {
    //    LoadJSON();// this isn't necessary because I am calling the LoadJSON function from another class.
    }

    public void LoadJSON()
    {
            Debug.Log(json_data);
            json_data = Resources.Load(filename).ToString();
            Eng_WB_Question_Wrapper loaded_data = JsonUtility.FromJson<Eng_WB_Question_Wrapper>(json_data);
            gamedata = loaded_data.questions;
            controller.gamedata_loaded(gamedata);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: You can use a TextAsset to load the JSON-file (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583104/unity-load-text-from-resources)

Comment: `Resources` is not `StreamingAssets`

Comment: @Stevy I'm getting a null pointer reference on ADB.

Comment: @StevenDelrue I tried that as well, still getting the null pointer reference

Answer (score 1):

I am using UnityWebRequest to get the json file from the streaming asset folder. my code is:

```
void Awake()
    {

        filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "CountryCodes2.json");

             StartCoroutine(Example());  
    }

    IEnumerator Example() 
    {
        if (filePath.Contains("://")) 
        {
            UnityWebRequest www = new UnityWebRequest(filePath);
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();
            result = www.downloadHandler.text;
        }
        else
            result = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);

     }
```

you can read your json file like this.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet. Let me try this and get back to you.